How to mock the Twilio library in Laravel
I am using the Twilio library for php/laravel to send sms message. I would like to know how I could mock it in my tests, I just want to make sure the create method is call and return a correct message
SmsController.php
$twilio = new Client('xxxxxxxxx', 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');

$message = $twilio->messages->create(
    "whatsapp:+" . $request->input('user_phone'),
    [
        "mediaUrl" => [
            $request->input('url'),
        ],
        "from" => "whatsapp:+xxxxxxxxx",
    ]
);

return response(['message_sid' => $message->sid]);

This is the test:
use Twilio\Rest\Client;
  ....
  ....

    Http::fake();
    
        $mock = $this->partialMock(Client::class, function (MockInterface $mock) {
            $mock->shouldReceive('create')
                ->with(
                    "whatsapp:+xxxxxxxx",
                    [
                        "mediaUrl" => [
                            "https://url.com/image.jpg",
                        ],
                        "from" => "whatsapp:+xxxxxxxxx",
                    ]
                );
        });
    
        $this->postJson('/twilio/user-message')
            ->assertOk();

But I am getting this error:
[HTTP 401] Unable to create record: Authentication Error - invalid username
Maybe is because it is supposed to pass in the credentiales in the constructor, but even if I do that, I should not make http request in tests.
What can I do?

I don't have a specific answer, but have you looked through what the official library is doing as far as testing? https://github.com/twilio/twilio-php/blob/main/tests/Twilio/Unit/Rest/ClientTest.php

Understanding ServiceContainer is most important to use Laravel.
It makes it easier to mock any class.
AppServiceProvider
use Twilio\Rest\Client;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function register(): void
    {
        $this->app->bind(Client::class, function ($app) {
            return new Client('', '');
        });
    }

Controller
use Twilio\Rest\Client;

$twilio = app(Client::class);

$message = $twilio->messages->create()
//

Test
use Mockery;
use Mockery\MockInterface;
use Twilio\Rest\Api\V2010\Account\MessageInstance;
use Twilio\Rest\Client;
use Twilio\Rest\Api\V2010\Account\MessageList;

    public function test_twilio(): void
    {
        $this->mock(Client::class, function (MockInterface $mock) {
            $message = Mockery::mock(MessageInstance::class);
            $message->sid = 0;

            $messages = Mockery::mock(MessageList::class);
            $messages->shouldReceive('create')->andReturn($message);

            $mock->messages = $messages;
        });

        $response = $this->get('/twilio');

        $response->assertOk();
    }


I forgot to add add something, now is working, thanks
